# Normal distribution paint cans

Tags: probability

Hi I am wondering how to solve the following and if my approach makes sense.

Suppose there is a given machine that dispenses dye into cans, with normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2} =0.16$ If more than $6mL$ is released, then the can is void. Find the correct setting for $\mu$ such that only $1%$% of the cans are void

My thoughts:

Since we are allowed to use the tables for a standard normal distribution, I thought maybe I must convert it so that $Z$~$N(0,1)$ and I know that this can be done as $Z= \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$

Well I am looking for $1-P( 0 \lt X \lt 6) \lt 0.01$

$0-\mu \lt x-\mu \lt 6- \mu$

$$\frac{-\mu}{\sqrt{0.16}} \lt \frac{ x-\mu}{\sqrt{0.16}} \lt \frac{6-\mu}{\sqrt{0.16}}$$

Then I look on the chart to find the z that corresponds to being less that 0.01 and find $z=0.25$

So then would I set say $1-\frac{6-\mu}{\sqrt{0.16}}=0.25$

and doing so would give me $\mu=5.7$

But I dont know if this is correct or makes sense? Anyone can comment on this? And is this how I should approach this form of problem? Again, I am not really asking for an in depth solution , of course that would be nice. But I am mostly just looking for someone to either confirm that it is correct, or point out where it is not. Anyone at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you would do the following:

Choose $\mu$ so that if $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $0.16$ then $P(X>6)=0.01$. Thus $P \left (Z>\frac{6-\mu}{\sigma} \right )=0.01$ or $P \left ( Z>15-2.5\mu \right )=0.01$ (since $\sqrt{0.16}=0.4$). Then using a normal table, you want $15-2.5\mu=2.33$ (to two decimal places) so $\mu=\frac{12.67}{2.5} \approx 5.07$.

When proceeding this way, you should be careful that $P(X<0)$ is small, since in the "real world" form of the problem it is just zero. In this case it is definitely small enough.